# Powerdot oddities

Tags: beamer, powerdot

I have a couple of questions,

1. When I run `powerdot`, my pdf file contains an extra page before title page with the word preamble of bottom left, how can I get rid of it?
2. In addition to the style files that are discussed in the powerdot manual (version 1.4h), I have seen a couple of others on the internet including `jena` and `umass amherst` styles. Are there any other slides out there? Is there a site that collects all these additional styles?
3. Does there exist a style that offers blocks (theorems, lemmas, exercises, etc.) similar to those offered in `beamer`? `jena` has blocks and exercises but those are not adequate. I am looking for a general block structure similar to `beamer` that can be used in all (or many) `powerdot` styles.
4. Is `powerdot` currently maintained and developed?

Comment: On this Q&A side it's better to write single questions instead of listing several questions at once, even if they are related.

Comment: Update your powerdot version and posting the same question in several groups at the same time is not a good choice ...

Answer (score 8):

1. The most current version of [`powerdot`](http://ctan.org/pkg/powerdot) (1.4h) does not yield this problem. However, since you mention that you are running the most current version, it may be unrelated to `powerdot`. For example, even compiling the following MWE

   ```
   \documentclass{powerdot}
   \begin{document}
   \begin{slide}{a slide}
     Contents of the slide.
   \end{slide}
   \section{first section}
   \begin{slide}{another slide}
     Contents of the slide.
   \end{slide}
   \begin{note}{personal note}
     The note.
   \end{note}
   \section{the end}
   \end{document}
   ```

   produces:

   [image: powerdot MWE]

   Note that `powerdot` produces graphics made by [`pstricks`](http://ctan.org/pkg/pstricks) and therefore require a `latex`->`dvips`->`pstopdf` (or `xelatex`) compilation sequence.
2. `powerdot` provides 15 different styles, in addition to the default:

   - `default` (shown above) - it comes in 6 different palettes: `blue` (default), `red`, `green`, `yellow`, `brown` and `purple`
   - `simple`
   - `tycja`
   - `ikeda`
   - `fyma` (based on [`prosper`](http://ctan.org/pkg/prosper)) - it comes in 5 different palettes: `blue` (default), `green`, `gray`, `brown` and `orange`
   - `ciment` (converted from `prosper`)
   - `elcolors`
   - `aggie` (converted from `prosper`)
   - `husky`
   - `sailor` - it comes with 5 different palettes: `Sea` (default), `River`, `Wine`, `Chocolate` and `Cocktail`
   - `upen`
   - `bframe`
   - `horatio`
   - `paintings` - it comes in 10 different palettes based on paintings: `Syndics` (default), `Skater`, `GoldenGate`, `Lamentation`, `HolyWood`, `Europa`, `Moitessier`, `MayThird`, `PearlEarring` and `Charon`
   - `klope` - it comes in 4 different palettes: `Spring` (default), `PastelFlower`, `BlueWater` and `BlackWhite`
   - `jefka` - it comes in 4 different palettes: `brown` (default), `seagreen`, `blue` and `white`
   - `pazik` - it comes in 2 different palettes: `red` (default) and `brown`

   All the above in-house styles can be viewed on [this `powerdot` gallery page](http://www.shantanukulkarni.org/powerdot/pdgallery.html), or by viewing chapter **7 Available styles** of the [`powerdot` documentation](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/powerdot/powerdot.pdf) (page 22). Then there are some alternative style that have been created but is not shipped with `powerdot`:

   - [`Jena`](http://www.personal.uni-jena.de/~xcr/v2/Dateien/File/neu-powerdot-jena/powerdot-Jena.sty)
   - [`umass amherst`](http://udrive.oit.umass.edu/aboelens/powerdot/powerdot-umass.zip)
   - [`tiger`](http://csgsa.cs.clemson.edu/seminar/tools06/docbook/html/ch02s06.html)

   Most styles are custom-made and there is no `powerdot` style repository, as far as I know. However, the [`powerdot` documentation](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/powerdot/powerdot.pdf) describes how to generate your own (see chapter **9 Creating your own style**, page 28). Or you could just start with an existing template (one of the above) and modifying it to suit your needs. Moreover, a [`powerdot` mailing list](http://www.freelists.org/list/powerdot) exists in the style of a mailing forum.
3. Since the `Jena` style already provides a at least two blocks (as is visible in the `Jena` demo, I would suggest taking that as your starting point to develop your own blocks. Or, consider viewing the other custom styles above and see how the modifications are defined. Since `powerdot` relies on the graphical components of `pstricks`, the [`pstricks` documentation](http://mirror.ctan.org/graphics/pstricks/base/doc/pstricks-doc.pdf) is a good point of reference on the type of modifications that are out there.
4. In general, to see who the active maintainers of a package/class is, [visit the corresponding CTAN mirror](http://ctan.org/pkg/powerdot).

Comment: you do not need the sequence latex->dvips->ps2pdf, because running `xelatex` is also possible. And where is the sense to copy the complete contents from a webpage instead of providing a link?

Comment: @Herbert: Sorry, forgot about `xelatex`. I sometimes find that providing an image of something (a web page, or a graphic of the output, whatever) provides *immediate* context, and is therefore sensible. Moreover, reference to `powerdot`'s home on CTAN is given throughout the post.

Comment: @Herbert: This running the example with `xelatex` does not work (see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/29607/powerdot-cannot-be-compiled-under-xelatex-how-to-solve-it/29611#29611).

Comment: @Carambir: you are right, there is a problem with the hyperref part, will see what I can do ...

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your question 4.: [`powerdot`](http://ctan.org/pkg/powerdot) is currently maintained by Hendri Adriaens. The current version is 1.4h of 2011/05/17.