# Powerdot cannot be compiled under xelatex; how to solve it?

Tags: xetex, errors, powerdot

I use Tex Live 2011 and test a simple example:

```
\documentclass{powerdot}
\begin{document}
\begin{slide}{a slide}
Contents of the slide.
\end{slide}
\section{first section}
\begin{slide}{another slide}
Contents of the slide.
\end{slide}
\begin{note}{personal note}
The note. \end{note}
\section{the end}
\end{document}
```

I can compile it using the compilation sequence: `latex`->`dvips`->`pstopdf`, but I can't compile it under `xelatex`. The error is

```
l.3932 \ProcessKeyvalOptions{Hyp}
```

How can this be solved?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Powerdot (which depends on pstricks) is not compatible with XeLaTeX. If you absolutely need to use XeLaTeX, then you should switch to [`beamer`](http://ctan.org/pkg/beamer).

Comment: But pstricks should be compatible with XeTeX. At least Herbert always says so (and he should know).

Comment: @Herbert sometimes overstates things. :-) There are still certain limitations. In the case of powerdot, there are lots of specials built into the code, and there is no way of choosing the driver. It's possible that one could make powerdot compatible with xelatex, but it would involve an awful lot of work as far as I can tell. I'll be happy to be proven wrong!

Comment: @Caramdir Interestingly, Herbert states in the comments to this answer [Powerdot oddities](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/27369/powerdot-oddities/28005#28005) that `xelatex` *can* be used, but I'm not sure how.

Comment: @AlanMunn,:-), I read Herbert's answer of the question, then I am confused why I can't use `xelatex`. thanks.

Comment: @PigCry Although I appreciate your accepting this answer (and at the moment, I think it is the correct one) you might want to wait until Herbert actually weighs in on the issue. Alternatively, you can keep it accepted for now, and if there is an actual solution, you can change the accepted answer.

Comment: See Herbert's comment to http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/27369/powerdot-oddities/28005#28005